# How to divide and sort an array in defined order

Tags: ruby, algorithm

### Input

```
cycle = 4
order = []
order[0] = [
  /foobar/, /vim/
]
order[1] = [ /simple/,/word/, /.*/ ]
record = [ 'vim', 'foobar', 'foo', 'word', 'bar', 'something', 'something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4']
```

### Requirement

I want to make a list named `report`.  Original source is `record` which is an one-dimension array. All elements of `record` will be split into different group and sorted.  The group and order is defined in `order`.

### This is pseudo code:

```
order.each do |group|
  group.each do |pattern|
    record.each do |r|
      if r =~ pattern
        @report[# of group][# of  row][ # of element (max is 4th)] = r 
      end
    end
  end    
end
```

Please note:

1. the element number in a `[row]` is `4` which is defined in `cycle`.
2. `[# of row]` :  If `# of element` > 4 ,  `# of row` will  + 1
3. Every element(string) in `report` is unique.

### Expected output:

```
require 'ap'
ap report

 [
    [0] [
        [0] [
            [0] "foobar",
            [1] "vim"
        ]
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] [
            [0] "word",
            [1] "foo",
            [2] "bar",
            [3] "something"
        ],
        [1] [
            [0] "something1",
            [1] "something2"               
            [2] "something3"
            [3] "something4"

        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: What are the contents of `group`? You don't have it defined anywhere, and say that it's defined in `order`, but use `group`.

Comment: There are two `group` in `order`, says `order[0]` and `order[1]`

Comment: Your result doesn't make any sense since you have a matcher `/.*/` but your result doesn't include `"foo"` or `"bar"`.

Comment: You have `[# of row]` in your output, but haven't defined what a row is.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated. Hope it is more clearly.

Comment: @heymike You still don't explain why neither `"foo"` nor `"bar"` is in the results.

Comment: Oops. update again. Sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (though it's not very pretty):

```
report = []
record.uniq!
order.each_with_index do |group, gi|
  group.each do |pattern|
    record.select { |r| r =~ pattern }.each do |match|
      report[gi] ||= [[]]
      report[gi] << [] if report[gi].last.length == cycle
      report[gi].last << match
    end
    record.delete_if { |r| r =~ pattern }
  end
end

puts report.inspect
#=> [[["foobar", "vim"]], [["word", "foo", "bar", "something"], ["something1", "something2", "something3", "something4"]]]
```

Note that `record` is mutated, so if you need it to remain the same you should `dup` it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. I'm still not entirely happy with this -- couldn't figure out how to boil down the last two steps into one. Also it ended up having more lines than [Andrew Marshall's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211563/andrew-marshall) answer. Boo.

Spec attached.

```
require 'spec_helper'

def report(cycle, order, record)
  record.uniq!
  order.each_with_index.map do |pattern_list, index|
    pattern_list.map do |pattern|
      record.each_with_index.inject([]) do |memo, (item, item_index)|
        memo.tap do
          if pattern =~ item
            memo << item
            record[item_index] = nil
          end
        end
      end
    end.flatten
  end.map do |items|
    items.each_with_index.group_by do |item, index|
      index.div(cycle)
    end.map do |ordering, item_with_index|
      item_with_index.map(&:first)
    end
  end
end

describe 'report' do
  let(:cycle) { 4 }
  let(:order) { [
    [/foobar/, /vim/],
    [/simple/,/word/, /.*/]
  ] }
  let(:record) {
    [ 'vim', 'foobar', 'foo', 'word', 'bar', 'something', 'something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4']
  }

  it "just works" do
    report(cycle, order, record.dup).should == [
      [["foobar","vim"]],
      [["word","foo","bar","something"],["something1","something2","something3","something4"]]
    ]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can use `each_with_index` which works similar to `each` but gives you the index if the loop as the second parameter.

I can't give you a full example sadly, as I didn't fully understand your use case. However with the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) you should be able to proceed.